# Problems with libraries for BQ769x0

Tags: c++, arduino, i2c

Im reverse engineering a bms. i have all the hardware connections down. it has a stm32f103c8, and bq7693003 with CRC. there are 2 libraries for this chip but both are not working! this is a picture of the bms. and this is the model of the bms. I'm using the example code in the github repo. the library I'm using is called: [10s_Ti_BQ76930_BMS](https://github.com/mikethezipper/10s_Ti_BQ76930_BMS)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNZzC.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nNPj.jpg)

after having one of the gpios as the boot pin for the BQ7693003 it boots up and says this in the serial console:

```
8
0x08
Starting BMS object
Starting wire.begin
starting variable initialization
Starting boot pin check
Determining i2c address and whether CRC is enabled
Address and CRC detection successful
Address:  8
CRC Enabled:  1
```

And it gets stuck there.

In the `bq769x0.cpp` i uncommented the BootPin code to start my bq7693003 automatically. before it was not turning on. but now it does and gets stuck as mentioned above.

```
  // Boot IC if pin is defined (else: manual boot via push button has to be 
  // done before calling this method)
  Serial.println("Starting boot pin check");
  if (bootPin >= 0)
  {
    pinMode(bootPin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(bootPin, HIGH);
    delay(5);   // wait 5 ms for device to receive boot signal (datasheet: max. 2 ms)
    //pinMode(bootPin, INPUT);     // don't disturb temperature measurement
    delay(1000);  // wait for device to boot up completely (datasheet: max. 10 ms)
  }
```

Theres also another problem it will not compile because of this:

```
      // check for overrun of millis() or very slow running program
      if (abs(secSinceInterrupt - secSinceErrorCounter) > 2) {
        secSinceErrorCounter = secSinceInterrupt;
      }
```

I think i fixed this by using `fabs` instead of `abs`.

i added various delays to the code but still it isint working properly.

Im really not sure what to do, as i have no idea how to code for I2C and this chip. also, i have tried the [LibreSolar](https://github.com/LibreSolar/bq769x0-arduino-library) library it gets far to the clearing of various errors such as XR, Alert, UV, OV.. etc but gets stuck after clearing the XR error.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after partially re-writing the whole library from scratch, I realized that the original author had some mistakes or something I'm not sure... if anyone knows please share so that there is a reason behind this fix.

First i changed `byte bq769x0::updateBalancingSwitches(void)` to `void bq769x0::updateBalancingSwitches(void)` in`bq769x0.cpp`

then I changed `byte updateBalancingSwitches(void);` to `void updateBalancingSwitches(void);` in `bq769x0.h`

**and then finally i changed this portion of code from this:**

```
if (determineAddressAndCrc())
    {
        //debug prints to show that initial comms were successful
        Serial.println("Address and CRC detection successful");
        Serial.print("Address:  ");
        Serial.println(I2CAddress, HEX);
        Serial.print("CRC Enabled:  ");
        Serial.println(crcEnabled);
        

        // initial settings for bq769x0
        writeRegister(SYS_CTRL1, 0b00010000);  // Turn ADC on and use internal die temp
        writeRegister(SYS_CTRL2, 0b01000000);  // switch CC_EN on

            // attach ALERT interrupt to this instance
    instancePointer = this;  //taken from arduino compatible code
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(alertPin), bq769x0::alertISR, RISING); //taken from arduino compatible code
        
        // get ADC offset and gain
        adcOffset = (signed int) readRegister(ADCOFFSET);  // convert from 2's complement
        adcGain = 365 + (((readRegister(ADCGAIN1) & 0b00001100) << 1) |
            ((readRegister(ADCGAIN2) & 0b11100000) >> 5)); // uV/LSB
    }
    else {
        // TODO: do something else... e.g. set error flag
#if BQ769X0_DEBUG
        Serial.println("BMS communication error\n");
#endif
    }



/*  // From original arduino startup code
  if (readRegister(CC_CFG) == 0x19)
  {
      Serial.println("Inside readregister for cc_cfg if");
    // initial settings for bq769x0
    writeRegister(SYS_CTRL1, B00011000);  // switch external thermistor and ADC on
    writeRegister(SYS_CTRL2, B01000000);  // switch CC_EN on

    // attach ALERT interrupt to this instance
    instancePointer = this;
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(alertPin), bq769x0::alertISR, RISING);

    // get ADC offset and gain
    adcOffset = (signed int) readRegister(ADCOFFSET);  // convert from 2's complement
    adcGain = 365 + (((readRegister(ADCGAIN1) & B00001100) << 1) | 
      ((readRegister(ADCGAIN2) & B11100000) >> 5)); // uV/LSB
    
    return 0;
  }
```

**to this in the bq769x0.cpp file:**

```
 if (determineAddressAndCrc())
    {
        //debug prints to show that initial comms were successful
        Serial.println("Address and CRC detection successful");
        Serial.print("Address:  ");
        Serial.println(I2CAddress, HEX);
        Serial.print("CRC Enabled:  ");
        Serial.println(crcEnabled);
    }



  // From original arduino startup code
  if (readRegister(CC_CFG) == 0x19)
  {
      Serial.println("Inside readregister for cc_cfg if");
    // initial settings for bq769x0
    writeRegister(SYS_CTRL1, B00011000);  // switch external thermistor and ADC on
    writeRegister(SYS_CTRL2, B01000000);  // switch CC_EN on

    // attach ALERT interrupt to this instance
    instancePointer = this;
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(alertPin), bq769x0::alertISR, RISING);

    // get ADC offset and gain
    adcOffset = (signed int) readRegister(ADCOFFSET);  // convert from 2's complement
    adcGain = 365 + (((readRegister(ADCGAIN1) & B00001100) << 1) | 
      ((readRegister(ADCGAIN2) & B11100000) >> 5)); // uV/LSB
    
    return 0;
  }
```